# How can we run Softlayer python API in parallel

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to run Softlayer Python API in one go, is there any way to do that?

Suppose,
I want to change snapshot scheduling time of 10 volumes in one go, instead of running separate API one by one for all 10 volumes.

Can someone please help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible you only can edit a schedule at once using the API, currently only to order and in some cases upgrade of servers it is possible to do it over several resources.

Regards